# What is the benefit of creating an unconnected socket in Java?

Tags: java, networking

In the code I'm studying, I see this line:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket();
```

So this is just a raw socket, connecting to nowhere? Why would you use this kind of socket that is not bound to a port?

I see [on the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoLinger%28boolean,%20int%29) that it is "with the system-default type of SocketImpl."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this when you want to connect with a timeout:

```
Socket s = new Socket();
try
{
    s.connect(address, timeout);
}
catch (SocketTimeoutExceptione exc)
{
    // connect timeout
}
```